# After .load() of div#content events from javascript are not binding to buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My javascript gets loaded on the webpage. Then when I .load() a div from a different PHP file, the javascript events don't bind to the content from the new div. Why is this not happening? And is there a fix for it?

Comment: It seems you are looking for "event delegation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code may not work if you add element after the document is loaded. You need event delegation to make it work try following format.

```
$(document).delegate( ".class or #id", "load",
    function(e) {
        alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "event delegation" or you may write JavaScript code that you want to execute in .load() callback function.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
    // write code to execute after the content is loaded
});
```